# Stories to read - Google

Tags: google-chrome, android

This may seem like a basic question but I really don't know the answer to it.

So... on my Android mobile phone when I click "Google",
it shows me a page with some **stories to read** which are quite relevant
based on my interests (Google knows my interests based on previous searches,
tracking, etc.).

How do I do the same thing e.g. in Chrome on my laptop?
How do I make this **stories to read** page appear?
Is that possible?

By the way, I installed a Chrome plugin/app called "Google news". It has a section called "For you".

That gives me some set of stories. They seem close to what I get on my phone.

Is that the right thing? Seems so to me.

Comment: https://nationalinterest.org/blog/techland/google-news-vs-google-discover-what-difference-154666

Comment: https://support.google.com/assistant/thread/55221012?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Google News web app for computers has a section called *For you*. It shows a page with some stories to read which are quite relevant based on your interests, the same as it does on Android phones.

It works in Chrome without installing the plugin as long as you are signed in to Google on Chrome. That way Google knows your interests based on previous searches, tracking, etc.

[image]

Comment: Hi. I have found you among the users that have voted this year in Web Applications. It's important that you check out the Community Bulletin and [meta.se] as soon as possible if you haven't already. It's crucial that you participate in the ongoing election for the Web Applications community moderator. For more information on how to do so, please visit [2023 Community Moderator Election](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5057/).